# ios 13 Navigation Controls disappears while sliding down the picker in the CNContactViewController for adding Profile picture?

Tags: ios, navigationbar, cncontactstore, cncontactviewcontroller

[image]
After clicking on AddPhoto
[image]
Observe while slidingdown controller cancel, newcontact and done disappears.
[image]

```
var contact = new CNMutableContact
            {
                // Given and family names.
                FamilyName = participant.LastName,
                GivenName = participant.FirstName,
                //Note = participant.Note,
                OrganizationName = participant.Company,

            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.IconUrl))
            {
                NSUrl url = new NSUrl(participant.IconUrl);
                UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromUrl(url));
                NSData data = image.AsPNG();
                contact.ImageData = data;
            }
       var contactViewController = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact(contact);

            contactViewController.Delegate = this;
```

In this section we add the contact with the existing data. 
And then adding the contactview controller as a present view controller.

```
var nc = new UINavigationController(contactViewController);
            this.PresentViewController(nc, true, () => {
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running this on a later version that IOS 8 , Swift now has the ability to enable disable scrolling of the navigation bar view . (If we are talking about the same thing.) . I thinkn the problem lies in your navigation controller instead of the above code .

You can use 
`self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false`

to disable the hiding of the navigation bar on scrolling and swipping , although This requires that your ViewController is embedded in a NavigationController. All child VC of the NavigationController will inherit this behaviour, so you might want to enable/disable it in viewWillAppear.

You could also disable this in your storyboard by setting the navigation controller -> shownavigationbar

[image: storyboard Hierarchy]
[image: Attribute section of the navigation controller]

Comment: How can we get the access for the viewwillappears in the ContactViewController? For reference i have attached the screenshot in the question

Comment: can you please attach an image of the view before scrolling so i can see the position of the navigation controller as well , also could you attach any code on the the place where u initialize the navigation controller with it's attributes

Comment: i alos attached some images to help using the storyboard navigation tags take a look and try it out as well

Comment: okay in your case it could be 2 reasons , either you have not disabled `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false` like i mentioned or when you click on add photo the frame sizes change causing the view it self to change width . and if you are adjusting the sizes of a view somewhere that method might be getting called . so the navigation width is not changed so the view wont be able to have enough space to render the navigation Controller.  First go to your `CNContactViewController` and in ViewWillAppear add the code i added above

Comment: I dont know if you can notice but it seems the last image you attached has less top margin than the one before , check the constraint updates . Do you adjust your heights or widths when you render the new component

Comment: I think this is not the case as the CNContactViewController has its own width. Even CNContactViewController is the iOS own class. How can i get the Control over the ViewWillAppear()?

Comment: what do you mean by how can you get access? in your CNContactViewController do you not have a method called ViewWillAppear () ? after ViewDidLoad() or something , if not add it inside the CNContactViewController class just like a normal method

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactviewcontroller , It is a inbuilt class we cannot change anything in it. So how do we call its lifecycle methods?